# why my "text" div's height takes all float divs into consideration?

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

I have four divs in the container, three of them are float and the last one is normal div without float. Why is my text div put beneath all three float divs and the height of my text div adds up all three float divs' height together? Theoretically，float elements are taken out from the element flow, so my text div should be placed on the very top of the container and it's height should just be the line height? please help me.

```css
#fd
{
 width:100px;
 height:150px;
 background-color:red;
 float:left; 
}
#sd
{
 width:150px;
 height:100px;
 background-color:blue;
 float:left; 
}
#td
{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background-color:green;
 float:left; 
}
#container
{
 width:300px;
 height:500px;
 background-color:darkgray;
}
#text
{
 background-color:aqua;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="basic.css">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id=container>
<div id=fd></div>
<div id=sd></div>
<div id=td></div>
<div id=text>aaaaaaabbbbb</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because the text has no white space and also there's no room at the top of the container. Therefore it wraps and increases the height of his parent (having cyan background). In order to break the word add `  word-break: break-all;` to the element.

Comment: @HashemQolami But red, blue, green divs are float elements. The text div should be the first element in the container div, why text div even look at float divs and no room at the top of container?

Comment: Floated elements are **not** completely removed from document flow. They are just placed along the left or right side of their container, allowing the line-boxes flow along the side of the float.

Answer (score 2):

As a simple illustration, consider your mark-up and the following CSS.

In CSS, the floated elements are first taken out of the flow and the regular content positioned.

Then the floated element are allocated space by wrapping the content around them such that the floated elements are placed as far left and as close to the top edge of the containing block as possible (taking into account other floated elements).  The text/content wraps around the edges of the floated elements.

To get a full appreciation of the nuances, you need to read the CSS specification about how floats work.

Ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats

In your example, because the floated elements are either wide enough or tall enough, the regular, inflow content starts below the bottom edge of the floated elements, which is as close to the top edge of the parent block that the content can appear after taking into account the dimensions of the floated elements.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  overflow: auto;
}
.floater {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
#fd {
  background-color: red;
}
#sd {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}
#td {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="floater" id="fd"></div>
  <div class="floater" id="sd"></div>
  <div class="floater" id="td"></div>
  <div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer facilisis velit ut neque tempor quis cursus tortor suscipit. Curabitur rutrum magna vitae arcu pharetra eget cursus ante accumsan. Nunc commodo malesuada adipiscing.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all your container width is 300px and ur 3 divs are 350px wide.this means its overflowing or out of the container to push the text div.if that dosen't help Try Useing 
    z-index:9999;
    position:absolute;
    width:80%;
for text div

Comment: Sir, what I dont understand is red, blue, green divs are float elements. The text div should be the first element in the container div, why text div even look at float divs and no room at the top of container?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve but if you place the text div at the top and then place a clearing element after it (before the three floated divs) you will end up with the text at the top. Although I did have to change the width of one of the divs to make them all fit in the 300px width container .. see below:

HTML

```
<div id=container>
<div id=text>aaaaaaabbbbb</div> 
<br class="clear" />
<div id=fd></div>
<div id=sd></div>
<div id=td></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#fd {
width:100px;
height:150px;
background-color:red;
float:left; 
}
#sd {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:blue;
float:left; 
}
#td {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:green;
float:left; 
}
#container {
width:300px;
height:500px;
background-color:darkgray;
}
#text {
background-color:aqua;
}
.clear {
float: none;   
}
}
```